# Can't call to model

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Vehicle.php ( app\Vehicle.php file )

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vehicles extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'serie';
    protected $fillable = ['serie', 'color', 'power', 'capacity', 'speed'];
    protected $hidden = ['serie'];

    public function maker()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Maker');
    }
}
```

VehicleController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Vehicle;
class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::all();

        return response()->json(['data'=> $vehicles], 200);
    }
}
```

Below is my route list

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                               | Name                   | Action
                 | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------
-----------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | makers                            | makers.index           | App\Http\Controllers\MakerController
@index           | web        |
|        | POST      | makers                            | makers.store           | App\Http\Controllers\MakerController
@store           | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | makers/{makers}                   | makers.update          | App\Http\Controllers\MakerController
@update          | web        |
|        | DELETE    | makers/{makers}                   | makers.destroy         | App\Http\Controllers\MakerController
@destroy         | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | makers/{makers}                   | makers.show            | App\Http\Controllers\MakerController
@show            | web        |
|        | POST      | makers/{makers}/vehicle           | makers.vehicle.store   | App\Http\Controllers\MakersVehicleCo
ntroller@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | makers/{makers}/vehicle           | makers.vehicle.index   | App\Http\Controllers\MakersVehicleCo
ntroller@index   | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | makers/{makers}/vehicle/{vehicle} | makers.vehicle.update  | App\Http\Controllers\MakersVehicleCo
ntroller@update  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | makers/{makers}/vehicle/{vehicle} | makers.vehicle.show    | App\Http\Controllers\MakersVehicleCo
ntroller@show    | web        |
|        | DELETE    | makers/{makers}/vehicle/{vehicle} | makers.vehicle.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\MakersVehicleCo
ntroller@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | vehicles                          | vehicles.index         | App\Http\Controllers\VehicleControll
er@index         | web        |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------
```

when I call to myapp.com/vehicles, it show me 'Class 'App\Vehicle' not found' error. I have also Maker controller and Maker model. I can call myapp.com/makers and it also return properly. Please point me where is my weakness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named your class `Vehicles` not `Vehicle`. You should name it `Vehicle` make sure it is `Vehicle.php` and you will be fine.

The relationship should have the Fully Qualified Class Name in it as well:

```
public function maker()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Maker');
    // or
    return $this->belongsTo(Maker::class);
    // assuming they are in the same namespace
}
```